# Browser appends a '?' to links on page, but the '?' does not appear in the source

Tags: htaccess, url, apache, browsers

I'm a little puzzled with the following problem:

When I hover over a link a WordPress site I'm looking after, I can see that the URL is `https://xxxxxxx.com/apply-now/?`

All the links on the page have an `?` appended to the end of them.

I'm not sure where this is being set, and to make matters more confusing, the `?` does not appear when you view the page source for the page. i.e. the anchor tag would look like `href="https://xxxxxx.com.au/apply/"`

I've had a look through some of the places I would expect this to be set, but I can't see anything i.e. bitnami.conf, apache.conf, htaccess.conf, etc.

It's a Bitnami stack, with apache, serving a WP site.

I can't seem to find a plugin that might be rewriting things.

It seems like something is adding a parameter to the URL on every single page, which ends up confusing crawlers like Screaming Frog and GoogleBot.

Any suggestions?

Cheers

Comment: Do you have any rewrite rules (either in .htaccess or in apache conf)?  Can you [edit] you post to include them.   Especially any that have the QSA (query string append) flag.

Comment: Could this be caused by JavaScript?   Do you see the question mark added via a redirect if you test with https://curl.se  on the command line like `curl --head https://example.com/page`?

Comment: to checkit  first: disable your browser javascript.
for example  Turn Off JavaScript in Firefox
see:
https://www.lifewire.com/disable-javascript-in-firefox-446039

Comment: `.com/apply-now/` vs `.com.au/apply/` - Is this just a typo in the question, or is the URL-path and TLD also changing on hover?

Comment: If you only see this when "hovering over a link" (and presumably persists when you follow the link) then this can only be client-side, not server-side (eg. URL rewriting) as appears to be the focus in the question. How is this "confusing crawlers"? Are they issuing a warning? Duplicate URLs?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with more details as requested in the comments so that the question can be re-opened.